# Is $\operatorname{End}(V)\simeq M_n(D)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $D$ be a division ring, and $V$ a vector space over $D$, such that $\dim_DV=n$ where $2\le n<+\infty$.

Then I must prove that $R:=\operatorname{End}(V)$ is a prime ring (a ring $R$ is prime if $aRb=0\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;a=0\;\vee\;b=0$) but not an integral domain.

I'm pretty sure about the correctness of my argument (which won't be written). My doubt is about the following preliminary consideration, on which the whole argument is based.

Every couple of $n-$dimensional $D$ vector space are isomorphic, hence every $n-$dimensional $D$ vector space is isomorphic to $D^n$.

Thus $R:=\operatorname{End}(V)\simeq\operatorname{End}(D^n)\simeq M_n(D)$ (this last one is the ring of $n\times n$ matrices over $D$).

Thus I simply worked with $M_n(D)$ to prove the initial claim. Is this correct?

Comment: So what does a mean for a vector space to be $n$-dimensional?

Comment: That it admits $n$ elements which are linearly indipendent (over $D$) and that generate the whole $V$. What do you want me to tell with this question?

Comment: Ah, so your question is *only* about $\operatorname{End} D^n \cong M_n(D)$? You can write down the isomorphism known from linear algebra. It works. (If you don’t know it, guess it, check it. It works.)

Comment: You need an "op" somewhere.

Comment: Well, actually. Come to think of it. It probably goes like $\operatorname{End} R^n \cong M_n (R^\mathrm{op})$. Doesn’t matter much, though, because the opposite ring of a division ring is again a division ring and the definition of prime rings seems to be symmetric.